# What is the best data structure to store this data on mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I'm designing a news publishing website. I want to allow my users to pick their favorite news and store them in a list. Any time a user wants to show his favorites, the news should be sorted by date and shown.

The structure to store is currently like this:

```
favorite_table = 
{
    user_id,
    data
}
```

All news are stored in the data field like this:

```
[{date:news_id},{date:news_id},{date:news_id]
```

Since all values are sorted by date, is it a good structure to store news? I have to append data whenever it arrives. Is my structure suitable for my purpose or is there a better structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure looks correct. You are storing only news_id in the data field and that's a smarter implementation because storing complete document will cause a lot of moving and writing by MongoDB every time a new news is added to favorites by the user.

Reason, which you probably already know, is that a new document is created on every update. Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/#upsert.

Also i think that as a business rule you should restrict the number of news items that can be set as favorite by the user. Allowing this list to grow indefinitely will not be a good idea for the embedded design.

In case you want an unlimited number of favorites, you better create a separate collection for that and then to get all the favorites by a user use $match (on user's id) and $sort (of news items) operators in an aggregation query to get the sorted list of favorite news items for the user.

Comment: Huge thanks for your information! do you know any tutorial to train me about MongoDB database design architecture?

Comment: I actually read the MongoDB manual from start till end. But you can read this part of the documentation : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/



I know of a few paid tutorials though. They are not exclusively about designing the schema but are helpful. Available on Pluralsight, they are: [this](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=mongodb-introduction) and [this](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=mongodb-big-data-reporting)

If you can't get the subscription, maybe try torrenting them if it is safe in your country.