# Using MongoDB for a more traditional many to many use case

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, nosql

I am really new to Mongo DB after spending a few years in the relational DB camp. I understand the idea of NoSQL, but somehow, I can't make myself envision anything more than using it for caching and fast retrieval of data.

I have a typical many-to-many situation to solve. Items get added to collections,  where multiple items can fit in one collection,  and vice versa. How can I solve this using Mongo DB, without duplicating the data? On the other hand, I would also like to avoid creating a collection full of ids only,  because afterwards I'd have to fetch the items one by one. If that's the case,  I'd even drop Mongo and go back to a more relational solution.

Is there anything that I'm missing with Mongo? If that's the case,  please let me know. I'd be glad to learn.

Comment: Im trying to understand how your question hasn't already been asked and answered hundreds of times already? Modeling data is well documented on the MongoDb web site. It's not clear why you're considering Mongo. It's not necessarily any faster than your existing SQL based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't have to shift to NoSQL if everything is fine for you in Relational DB. If there is some issue in Relational DB, try fixing it within the domain of relational DB only.

But if the issue is that data which you are storing in relational DB doesn't always have the same form OR you simply want to try NoSQL for the heck of it, then go ahead with NoSQL DBMS.

Since NoSQL DB's have no preset design therefore the best way to design your your database (and the collections within it) is by looking at the queries which you are going to perform on the DB. The best learning source for designing the database is the MongoDB docs on data modeling which are available on the MongoDB's page of [Data Models](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/).

You will find a lot of tutorials online for using MongoDB for querying an existing database but very few tutorials on designing the database in MongoDB. Reason:

1) 'No'SQL - i.e. there is no rule at all for designing. The best approach is probably 'query-driven', which means that you identify the queries you will run on DB and then design the DB so that those queries can run in the most efficient manner.

2) MongoDB is in its nascent stage. I see it adding new features pretty soon. Maybe then we will be able to freeze some guidelines for designing the MongoDB database.

Coming back to your question of designing many-to-many relations. In relational DBMS we create a table in the middle of the tables of that many-to-many relation. In MongoDB, we embed one table within another for this scene. It is same as de-normalizing a relational database. Information duplication is inevitable unless you decide to only embed the id's and leave the other table in a separate collection. Again, knowing your query in advance is the best guide.

A lot of questions have been asked on stackoverflow where people try to get their NoSQL design validated from people in the community. You can see those questions and get a feel of how you should approach designing your NoSQL DB in MongoDB. One sample question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976580/what-is-the-best-data-structure-to-store-this-data-on-mongodb/23976906). It simply recites again what I am saying to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will make sense if you could add concrete example ("documents" or "tables"). The basic rule when you work with documents is really to focus on the the way you will manipulate the data. (query vs write/update, ...) 
And based on this you will or will not duplicate the data, but for me I do not see any issue to duplicate the data, in many documents/collections, especially if you do not update them often. It makes the life of the developer a lot easier

I am inviting you to look to the following links:

- [Data Modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) :
- [MongoDB Applied Design Patterns (book)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449340040)

When you start your design you should try to "forget" your relational background to start with a fresh mind.

Also depending of the programming language you use you may find some ODM (Object Document Mapping) tools that help you, for example Mongoose in Node.js, Morphia in Java, ...

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed [DBrefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/), but as [WiredPrairie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95190/wiredprairie) suggested in the comments below, it shouldn't be used. It might also be that you just aren’t thinking very NoSQL - like, but still more in the relational world.

The reason why NoSQL DBs are so fast is limiting the functionality as well as handling denormalized data sets, this way you spare the joins.

So while DBrefs should work for you, it will be much slower than SQL’s Joins. Instead you could also ask yourself - when you have a Many-to-Many relationship between A and B, which data of B do you really need when you use A and vice versa. But this depends entyrely on your use case.

Just an example of a many-to-many relationship which could be easily resolved in MongoDB:

Users <-> Permissions (one user has multiple permissions, and one permission is used by multiple users) - however in 99% of the cases you want to see which permission a user has, therefore you’d save the permissions, or some description of it, … in the user object. And only in the 1% of the cases (or even less) when you really want to know which user has a permission, you can run a very slow query, but it won’t matter, since it’s almost never used.

Comment: DBRefs shouldn't be used in a modern MongoDb solution, and shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: That's why I suggested that he might want to rethink the data model and not simply map an sql schema to MongoDB

Comment: My feedback for your answer is that it seems like you're suggesting they might work.

Comment: OK thx, update my answer to state explicitly that it shouldn't be used.